# How to join multi arrays from Object properties in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and I have a problem as below: 
I have created an Object whose properties are arrays. For example:

```
$scope.myObject = {
   import: [ object1, object2,...,objectN ],
   export: [ object1', object2',...,objectN' ],
   ...
}
```

Now I want to create a new array which concats all arrays from myObject properties so that I can display them in HTML view with ng-repeat. 
This is my Plnk sample code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca8OX7kX8wV8JmRYJCzS?p=preview 
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With underscore or lodash :

```
_.flatten(_.values($scope.myObject));
```

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/6szuw3gq/1/)**

I've added also a plain JS (EcmaScript 5+) method :

```
$scope.myObjectJS = [];
Object.keys($scope.myObject).forEach(function(key) {
   $scope.myObjectJS = $scope.myObjectJS.concat($scope.myObject[key]);  
});
```

The fact that I use `Object.keys(obj)` instead of `for (var key in obj)` exempts us to check for `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems just correct with simple array/objects. In my case, it still return a blank array. Maybe it concats too soon when my properties still not get the results back from server?

Comment: The [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca8OX7kX8wV8JmRYJCzS?p=preview) you provided does not reflect the question. In the template, you are `ng-repeat`ing over a variable called `array` that does not even exist. Furthermore, I don't see any concat method of your data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right this should work.

```
var newArr = [];
for(var key in $scope.myObject){
  newArr = newArr.concat($scope.myObject[key]);
}
```

Comment: Need to assign result of concat() back into newArr.

Comment: Thanks but it returns the blank array. I have created Plnk to show my sample code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca8OX7kX8wV8JmRYJCzS?p=preview